# PyCharm error message

Tags: python, pycharm

What is the significance of this error message:

[image]

I just updated PyCharm and I don't know the significance of this error.

I understand that .xml is a markdown file (?), but without the .Rmd extension I'm not sure I can open it in RStudio to see when / by who it was created. It could have been a file created in the context of a Coursera course. A bit of research tells me that the .idea directory is a folder that python creates with every project (?).

Comment: What PyCharm plugins are you using? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know anything about Python. Where can I find the plug-in's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you change anything in your project folder recently?  Does the folder contain a .git subfolder?

Try going to the project folder root and issue this command:

```
git init
```

Comment: Do I go to the project folder root from within PyCharm?

Comment: Just making sure: do you have git properly configured on your computer?  You mentioned a Coursera course: is this a python project/folder that you started yourself from scratch, or did you import it into PyCharm from some other source?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm not quite sure (overlapping stuff) but I erased .idea and not it's not giving me the error message any longer.